# MongoDB $nin query exceeds BSON document size limitation

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am performing a simple query using Pymongo against a list of filenames:

```
db.FileAssets.find({'filename': {'$nin': filenames}}})
```

However, the query is throwing the `DocumentTooLarge` error.  The length of the `filenames` list is 152098 and the Python object size is 1320856.  Pymongo states the query is 20791219 bytes so I'm guessing that whatever MongoDB does internally to perform the $nin is overloading the doc size.  What is an alternative way to perform this query?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is about Response object. It can take too much memory in MongoDB.
Sometimes, adding new indexes can resolve this issues.